# crystal reports : limit subreport rows

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to limit the database field output in a subreport to just return the first record if there is more than one record?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this would work, or is what you are looking for, but try putting the field in the report header instead of the details section of the sub report.

Comment: don't know why i didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

You could also place your fields in the Details section and enable the 'Suppress if Duplicated' property on each field.